# RoundCube too many sleep connections in mysql

Tags: mysql, httpd, roundcube

we have a mail service with these details:

```
    1-Centos 6.4
    2:Postfix 2.6.6
    3:roundcube 0.8 
    4:dovecot 2.0.9.7
    5:mysql-server 5.1.71
```

everything is ok but in peak usage time roundcube sleeped connections increases from 1 or 2 or 3 to 270 in less than 10 minutes  and apache opened files (measured by lsof) increase from  4000 to 20000 in that peak time.

this is apache conf: (apache works in prefork mode)

```
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
TraceEnable off
LimitRequestLine 1024
LimitRequestFields 100
LimitRequestFieldsize 1024
LimitRequestBody 10241024
```

and here is mysql config:

```
secure_auth=1
local_infile=0
max_connections        = 600
max_allowed_packet    = 16M
key_buffer        =256M
wait_timeout=240
interactive_timeout=180
connect_timeout=10
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
```

when sleeped connections of roundcube increased to >100 ,almost  services (web,mail,mysql) go down....

thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: 1. How did you install your php? 2. How much your RAM/CPU? `free -m;cat /proc/cpuinfo;`

Comment: You have decide use prefork or apache worker , so read the following link : http://codebucket.co.in/apache-prefork-or-worker/

Comment: mysql down or apache ? or all of your machine ....?

Comment: install php from repository (php 5.2.10)
256G RAM
64 Cores CPU 2.4GHz

Comment: in peak time all services go down

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh aziz!
I know what is worker and prefork mode
and we decided to use prefork
everything is ok upon 3 months ago but now....

Comment: It's such as "Opened-Released connections", and you emulate a DOS attack(not syn, such as OpenDNS) , not you but only your kernel. i have a suggesstion: telnet from a secified machine and test your ip will be died or not. if die, be sure test your kernel and  your boot process.

Comment: Is it run under cluster management? Did you have any log in crash time? and paste ram and cpu situation in crash time

Comment: We use red hat cluster suite in failover mode but we freeze service for some reasons.
server don't crash! but services like apache and mysql go down  (CLI work too slow, because apache opened too many  file descriptor like these:
Wed Apr 9 13:30:18 IRDT 2014
  22288 apache,
     23 clam,
     29 dbus,
    175 dovecot,
   3033 dovenull,
     52 haldaemon,
     93 luci,
   1986 mail,
     70 mysql,
     29 ntp,
   1342 postfix,
     35 ricci,
   6513 root,
      1 USER,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now

After about 5 years

The problem has been detected and solved in few days.

It was so complicated for a Jr. System administrator like me ;)

There was a problem in GFS2 cluster file-system that my teammate prepared on iSCSI LUN and this issue led to various issues and problems in Dovecot and roundcube (and then apache)

for your information , when I pay attention to %wa parameter on top command , (it was about 90% ) , I thought (perhaps) there is problem in filesystem level.

Then I had decide to transfer all data to new cluster filesystem (ocfs2) because GFS was deprecated !

First of all, All data moved to new cluster file-system (on ocf2) then re-design whole system based on pacemake haproxy on debian wheezy!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is:

I have edit apache max_client option to lower value 256 --> 50
why!?

for (still) unknown issue all the preforked apache processes take CPU usage  about 100% (100% usage of that core running preforked apache process for few moments)

So system go Down , because system has 64 CPU cores when all the 256 processes of apache use 100% cpu usage , system and services go down

issue still exist but services has no problem
I think issue related to network attacks (our monitoring tools report many attacks per day), that sometimes make problem such as resource locking or something else

thank you for all suggestion.